# Stuck to select maximum row

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I have a table with columns:

```
ID | FULLNAME | VALUE
01   Joseph     10
02   Sam        50
...  ...       ...
```

I need to select row with maximum value, and show info like

```
FULLNAME | VALUE
```

I tried using group function `MAX()`, but I can't select fullname, because if I use it as a `GROUP BY` expression, it will select max in groups.

Other way, is to use `WITH` statement, order table by value desc, use

```
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS max_id
```

function and maximum value will be on max_id = 1, and then use

```
WHERE max_id = 1
```

to remove other rows.

But I think there is a way to do this better and I can't find one.

UPDATE:

A tricky solution to this problem is

```
SELECT *
FROM t t1
    LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.value<t2.value
WHERE t2.value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to sort the data and pull one row:

```
select t.*
from t
order by value desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want ties, you can add `with ties` to the `fetch first`.

Another method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value = (select max(t2.value) from t t2);
```

This can have very good performance with an index on `value`.

Comment: Thanks
I found a trickier way to do this, using joins



select *

from t t1

     left join t t2 on t1.value < t2.value

where t2.value is null